# Remove event with off without removing delegate

Tags: jquery, html, bind

I have two listenners in my code, the first one is for all elements with the attribute `data-listen-enter` in the document, I use `$(document).delegate` so new elements will listen to this event too

```
$(document).delegate('[data-listen-enter]', 'keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13)
        $($(this).data('listen-enter')).trigger('click');
});
```

The second one is after I open my "dinamic confirm" function, so when it shows up it listen when I press enter to confirm or cancel

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 13)
        $myConfirm.find('.myConfirm-confirm').trigger('click');
});
```

So when I click in confirm or cancel, it removes the event

```
$(document).off('keyup');
```

But it also removes the first event that listen to all elements with the attribute `data-listen-enter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered [event.namespace](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) in jQuery

I can give a name to my event so late I can specify exaclty witch one I want to remove

**all elements with the attribute data-listen-enter in the document**

```
$(document).delegate('[data-listen-enter]', 'keyup.listenEnter', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13)
        $($(this).data('listen-enter')).trigger('click');
});
```

**my "dinamic confirm"**

```
$(document).on('keyup.myConfirm', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 13)
        $myConfirm.find('.myConfirm-confirm').trigger('click');
});
```

**So when I click in confirm or cancel, it removes just the event from my dinamic confirm**

```
$(document).off('keyup.myConfirm');
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/off/) on this, you can specify which events to remove more granularly by supplying the handler function as well. To do that, you will need to specify the function as a variable.

```
var keyUpFunc = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13)
        $myConfirm.find('.myConfirm-confirm').trigger('click');
};

$(document).on('keyup', keyUpFunc);

//this should just remove the one event...
$(document).off('keyup', keyUpFunc);
```

Untested, but give it a shot.

Comment: Thank you so much Chris, but I discovered that I can use namespace in events, and specifying exactly witch one I want to remove, so I will answer my own Question, but I'm going to give you an Up cause your answer is useful